# Submitting an "AMP Form" using "action-xhr" causes a "Mixed Content" error when called from the Google AMP Cache but works fine outside it

Tags: xmlhttprequest, amp-html, amp-form

I have set up a "Star Rating" system on my AMP page and it works great from my site's version of the AMP page however, when I submit it from the AMP Cache version of the form I get a Mixed Content error even though I'm sure I've specified HTTPS in the action-xhr attribute of the form.

Works
https://healthand.com/au/topic/general-report/aeroplane-travel-amp

Doesn't Work
https://www.google.com/amp/s/healthand.com/us/topic/general-report/aeroplane-travel-amp

You will need to navigate to the end of the page to see the star ratings.

This is the error in the browser console.
[console error msgs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjWQR.png)

This is the form HTML taken from

https://www.google.com/amp/s/healthand.com/us/topic/general-report/aeroplane-travel-amp clearly showing the action-xhr="https://healthand.com/au/topic/add-new-rating" attribute set to HTTPS.

These are shots of the headers.

[header one pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbYgL.png)
[header two pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYtpq.png)

It looks like it is just converting from HTTPS to HTTP for no reason. The headers seem OK on the first entry but the second one is definitely HTTP.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: i am confused. the hosted version is solid. but the source code in the amp cache is different from the hosted version. for example, the tool-tips are different. and i see /us and /au. from my perspective, the source files are different.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like when the page is "imported" into the AMP cache quite a few changes are made to the "source", I guess so it can be served up super fast from the cache. The us, au... changes depending on your country so the correct language is displayed. The source that generates the pages is identical. Still in the AMP cached version the call to the action-xhr is definitely HTTPS. It really has me stumped. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the AMP cache "optimizes" the HTML. If the AMP cache version changed the https:// URL to http:// that could be a bug. I was wondering if the origin did something like redirect the user if no cookie set? Does your HTTP call to register the rating require cookies to work correctly?